# iPhone switch statement using enum

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have defined an enum in a header file of a class :

```
typedef enum{
 RED = 0,
 BLUE,
 Green
} Colors;

- (void) switchTest:(Colors)testColor;
```

and in the implementation file I have :

```
- (void) switchTest:(Colors)testColor{

   if(testColor == RED){
    NSLog(@"Red selected");    
   }

   switch(testColor){
    case RED:
    NSLog(@"Red selected again !");
    break;
    default:
    NSLog(@"default selected");
    break;
   }

}
```

My code compiles correctly without warrnings.
When calling the switchTest method with RED, the output is :
"Red selected"

**but once the first line of the switch runs, the application quits unexpectedly and without warrnings/errors.**

I don't mind using if/else syntax but I would like to understand my mistake.

Comment: Can you post some more code? Maybe the line or two where you are creating the Colors param and sending the switchTest: message?

Answer (score 14):

Works fine for me:

```
typedef enum{
    RED = 0,
    BLUE,
    Green
} Colors;

@interface Test : NSObject

- (void) switchTest:(Colors)testColor;
@end

@implementation Test

- (void) switchTest:(Colors)testColor {
    if(testColor == RED) {
    NSLog(@"Red selected");    
    }

    switch(testColor){
    case RED:
        NSLog(@"Red selected again !");
        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"default selected");
        break;
    }
}
@end


int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    Test *myTest = [[Test alloc] init];

    [myTest switchTest:RED];

    [myTest switchTest:RED];

    [pool drain];
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Pfitz Appreciate the edit. Is there now an extra `}` above the @end ? Makes it hard to follow and learn. Thanks.

Comment: How would you convert a string input to its corresponding enum value in a sane way?
For example:  you received  @"RED" as a string from a text input and want to put it through a switch statement without using a whole bunch of if else statements , how would you relate that to the enum list of NSUINumbers?

Answer (score 8):

In my case, the problem was that I defined the variable:

```
Colors *testColor; //bad
```

Instead of:

```
Colors testColor; //right
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Was pulling my hair about the same thing. A switch statement containing case values from an enum, that was defined differently depending on some #ifdef blocks. The case values were not recognized properly by the compiler within the switch, even though you could "print" them using an NSLog fine.

If a name is recognized properly it is shown in the wellnown blue-green color, if it isn't in black. My case values were shown in black. After quitting xcode and a restart all was fine.